# java performance issue - regular expression VS internal String method

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm having the following issue:
I have some string somewhere in my application that I want to check - the check is whether this string contains a character that is different than `" "`(white space), `/n` and `/r` 
For example:

- `"        g"`    -   Contains
- `"    /n   "`    -   Not Contains
- `"   "`          -   Not Contains

I want to do it in a reg expression, but I don't want to use the common pattern `.*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.* .` Instead, I want something like `.*[!" ""/n"/r"]`. (every character that is different than `" "` `"/r"` and `"n"`).

My problems are that

1. I don't know if this pattern is valid (the above isn't working)
2. I'm not sure if it would be me much faster then using the
                       regular Strings methods.

Comment: in my opinion iterating over characters would be the fastest method - your "pattern" is very simple and compiling it is wasted time. also, you might want to look at Character.isWhiteSpace()

Comment: By the way, you can use `matches` with `\S+` for checking. Efficiency wise, no comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you mean `\n` and `\r`, and in Java this means escaping the backslash as well with `\\n` and `\\r`.

Secondly, if you merely mean to catch any non-whitespace, just use the pattern `\\S*` or `[^\\s]`.  `\S` is non-whitespace, or `\s` is whitespace and `[^<charset>]` means "match anything that isn't one of these."

Thirdly, if this is a repeated check, be sure to only compile the regex once then use it multiple times.

Fourthly, follow usual strategy for profiling.  Firstly is this in a critical strip in your application?  If so then benchmark yourself.

Comment: I tryied to use the [^\\S] but it doesn't just doesn't works at all. Its results are incorrect

Answer (score 1):

here's something that does exactly what you want, but (like i said above), it'll be faster going over characters:

```
Pattern NOT_WHITESPACE_DETECTOR = Pattern.compile("[^ \\n\\r]");
Matcher m = NOT_WHITESPACE_DETECTOR.matcher("  \n       \r      bla        ");
if (m.find()) {
   //string contains a non-white-space
}
```

also note that the definition of whitespace in java is much wider than you specified, and even then there are whitespaces out there in unicode that java doesnt detect (there are libraries that do, however)